# Writing a method which updates the contractor in java

Tags: java

NOT create a new item, only want to modify an existing item.

```
Original Constrator:

public Item(String a, String b, String c, String d) {

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;

}
```

Want to write a method that updates the constrator,like

```
public void updateItem(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        XXXX(Not sure what to put here)
}
```

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: put same thing as used in constructor. just copy-paste it from the constructor.

Comment: Original constructor doesn't take `d`, but otherwise just use the same thing or add mutator methods (setters) for `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`. And then use them (with or without `updateItem`), but please use meaningful variable names in real code.

Comment: You can have multiple constructors as long as the order/type combination is different.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are used only for creating new objects (they allocate memory for the new object as well as initializing fields). If you want to update an existing object you'd make an instance method:

```
public void updateItem(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d. - d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void updateItem(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}
```

This does the same thing as the constructor, and resets the variables on an existing object. The only difference between a constructor and a regular method is that the constructor creates the object before performing the operation. As this is a normal method, it will overwrite the existing variables instead of creating an entirely new object.